# Remove 'related products' for single item page based on multiple categories in woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I would love to choose which category single-item pages show related items. We do not want all items in every category to show related items since some are special offers.

I have used this code to remove a single category:

```
/**
 * Removes Related Products from the Special Offer Products single item pages.
 *
 */

function wc_remove_related_products( $args )
{
    if (is_product() && has_term( 'Special Offer', 'product_cat'))
    {
        return array();
    } 

    return $args;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_related_products_args','wc_remove_related_products', 10);
```

This will remove related items from only 1 category.  So I have adjusted this code using an array / push_array as listed here

```
$special_categories = array();
array_push($special_categories, 'Special Offer');
array_push($special_categories, 'Train The Trainer');
array_push($special_categories, 'Teacher Training Registration');

function wc_remove_related_products( $args )
{
    if (is_product() && has_term($special_categories, 'product_cat'))
    {
        return array();
    } 

    return $args;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_related_products_args','wc_remove_related_products', 10);
```

However, it is now removing all related products from all categories. What am I missing?  I would love some ideas. I am just going through a PHP course and would love to figure this out for my clients.

---

UPDATE:

I have tried 2 other possible solutions based on other codes that I have seen or used, and altered them for this purposed but still not achieving the desired outcome:

```
$special_categories = array('Special Offer','Train The Trainer','Teacher Training Registration');

function wc_remove_related_products( $args )
{
    if (is_product() && has_term($special_categories, 'product_cat'))
    {
        return array();
    } 

    return $args;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_related_products_args','wc_remove_related_products', 10);
```

The code above removed all of the related products. This code below removed none.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', 'wc_remove_related_products' );
function wc_remove_related_products( $args ) {
        $args['exclude'] = array('59','60','61','233','234','220','235','236','237','238');
        return $args;
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you in advance!